# local mail setup to debug root cron jobs on debian

Tags: debian, cron, postfix

I'm running the following setup:
beaglebone black [wireless version - 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT] -- running debian 9.3 stretch.

I've attempted to install the latest postfix mail server -- just so 
I can read the debug messages from cron.

I notice that the mailque is full of emails to 
root@beaglebone.localdomain.

Yet, if I try to:

```
> sudo mail
```

I get :

```
no mail for root
```

**Question:
What should my root email address be ?**
Obviously not root@beaglebone.localdomain!

**Is there something wrong with either my postfix conf or the contab?**

My /etc/postfix/main.cf looks like this:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
relayhost =
```

The root contrab looks like this:

```
MAILTO="root@beaglebone.localdomain"
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
5,35 * * * * cd /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/ && Rscript /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/graph.R &>/home/debian/bbbwifilogger/cron.log
6,36 * * * * cd /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/ && cp /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/moist.png /var/www/html/
6,36 * * * * cd /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/ && cp /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/tdegc.png /var/www/html/
7,37 * * * * cd /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/ && cp /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/dnlddata.zip /var/www/html/
3,33 * * * * /etc/init.d/networking restart
10,40 * * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d "20 minutes") >> /home/debian/bbbwifilogger/bbblogger.log 2>&1
```

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mailbox full issue just increase email box size or rotate the mailbox.

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:

message_size_limit = 31457280
```

Comment: Sorry Ebin, as indicated, I am trying to send the email to a local email address -- ie on the machine. The machine is not always connected to the internet. As you can see from the config files, I've attempted to configure this. You can also see that I have set the MAILTO in crontab.

Comment: @user2449710 please see my update answer.

Comment: Hi Ebin, I don't think I have a mailbox full issue.  It's just not being directed to the correct address.